# Running gunicorn with threading

Tags: flask, server, gunicorn

I'm building a server with Flask/Gunicorn and Nginx. My script (Flask server) does two things with 'threading':

1. connect to MQTT broker
2. run a  flask server

But when i try using gunicorn: **gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app**, the first thread doens't run.

Here is the code (not complet):

```
import threading

def run_mqtt():
    while True:
        mqtt_client.connect(mqtt_server, port=mqtt_port)

def run_server():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_mqtt)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=run_server)
    t1.daemon = True
    t2.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Please help me, i have to find the solution very fast! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gunicorn is based on the pre-fork worker model. That means that when it starts, it has a master process and spawns off worker processes as necessary. Most likely the first thread did run, but you lost track of it in the other prefork processes.

If you want to have a background thread that flask controllers can interact with and share memory with, it's unlikely that gunicorn is a good solution for you.

Comment: Which solution would you recommend? uWSGI?